# How to edit column in CGridView

Tags: yii, cgridview

How is it possible, to make the columns in CGridView editable? i searched and find several extensions, but nothing works for me.
i'm doing something wrong or the extensions are buggy, i don't know.

can anyone help me please, and describe exactly, what i have to do, to make my columns in CGridView editable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yii-booster extension has class TbEditableColumn that implements column edit feature. You can look example [here](http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/widgets/editable/view/column.html). There is my example of code:

```
    array(
        'class' => 'YbEditableColumn',
        'name' => 'priority',
        'value' => '$data->priorityName',
        'sortable' => false,
        'editable' => array(
            'type' => 'select',
            'source' => Task::model()->getPriorities(),
            'url' => $this->createUrl('update'),
            'placement' => 'top',
        )
    ),
```

There is other extensions based on bootstrap Editable, like [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-bootstrap-editable/), may be you can check it too.

Comment: i try to install the extension, but there are several problems... the instructions dont show WHERE i have to put in some code, to get the extension work... eveytime "just use this snippet..." but they dont tell where o.O